# how to stop cloning of attribute or tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problems in Jquery. I want to clone a attribute or tag which is drag from one **div1** to another **div2** that is fine. **But problems is when i dragging or moving position of existing tag on div2 then cloning is star**

I want to cloning only when i drag from **div1** to **div2**, Please tell me where am i wrong and what is wrong.

**This is my div1**

```
<div class="md-card scroll-style">
                    <div class="draggable-items">
                        <img class="img_style" src="tools_icon/ic_text_format.svg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text Input" data-placement="bottom">
                        <div id="text_field_clone" class="draggable_items_hide">
                            <input type="text" name="text_field">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**This is div2**

```
<div class="droppable_box_style scroll-style" id="droppable-box">

                </div>
```

**This Jquery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".draggable-items").draggable({
                grid: [ 20, 20 ],
                appendTo: '#droppable-box',
                containment: "window",
                cursor: 'move',
                revertDuration: 100,
                revert: 'invalid',
                helper: 'clone'
            });

            $("#droppable-box").droppable({
                accept: ".draggable-items",
                drop: function (event, ui){

                    ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#droppable-box');

                    $("#droppable-box > .draggable-items").find(".img_style").hide();

                    $("#droppable-box > .draggable-items").find("#text_field_clone").removeClass("draggable_items_hide").addClass("show").resizable();

                    $("#droppable-box > .draggable-items").draggable();
                }
            });
            // $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });   
    </script>
```

**My layout like this**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Attach a cloning function to the Jquery mouseup event:

```
 $(selector).mouseup(function(){
    //put cloning code here
    });
```

[Refer Demo Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mup_mdown_ref)

Comment: thanks for replying, I found one solution if I will put Boolean variable on cloning (then Boolean value is false for drag tools then I can change position of tools) it's working. but then i drag another tool from first div1 then it is not cloning.

Comment: we can create dynamic array for dragging tools, when will we drag tools from div1 to div2 then Boolean value is changed means false.

Comment: yes,you can..bit i think this was the easiest one so i suggested

Comment: Sorry I can't understand please can you write properly with above code...